# Is a functor category of an $\mathbf{Ab}$-category an $\mathbf{Ab}$-category itself?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

In Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*, exercise 2.6.4 reads

> Show that $\operatorname{colim}$ is left adjoint to $\Delta$.
>     Conclude that $\operatorname{colim}$ is a right exact functor when
>     $\mathcal{A}$ is abelian (and $\operatorname{colim}$ exists).

in particular, $\mathcal{A}$ is required to be abelian because from what we learned in section 1.6 this implies that, for any category $C$, the functor category $\mathcal{A}^C$ is abelian. Then we have an adjoint pair of additive functors and we can conclude (he talks about exactness only for additive functors).

But, and *this* is my question, couldn't we use the same argument assuming less? Or, is it true that if $\mathcal{A}$ is an $\mathbf{Ab}$-category, then $\mathcal{A}^C$ is such, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If $X,Y \in A^C$ and $f,g : X \to Y$, then $f+g$ is defined by $(f+g)(c)=f(c)+g(c)$ for all $c \in C$. This *is* a morphism $X \to Y$, since for all $i : c \to c'$ we have

$$Y(i) (f+g)(c)=Y(i) (f(c)+g(c))=Y(i) f(c) + Y(i) g(c)=f(c') X(i) + g(c') X(i) = (f(c')+g(c')) X(i)=(f+g)(c') X(i).$$

Similarily $-f$ and $0$ are defined. It is obvious that $A^C$ becomes an $\mathsf{Ab}$-category.